# Continuity in functions with 2 variables

Tags: limits, functions, multivariable-calculus, continuity

Given ,

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} & (x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
      0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \\ 
\end{cases} $$

We need to check whether the function is continuous at $(0,0)$ or not.

I have come to the following conclusion. if *y=mx*

$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \dfrac{mx}{1+m}$

but I do not know if I'm right

Comment: Note that $2|xy|\leq x^2+y^2$, for all real numbers $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is much easier to see that since $$-1 \leq\frac{y}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\leq1$$
then by the squeeze theorem you know that since 
$$-|x| \leq\frac{xy}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}}\leq |x|$$
taking limits of both sides, you get that the limit of $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)$ tends to zero, so your function is continuous, nonmatter what "direction" you are coming from.

Answer (score 3):

Convert to polar:

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r^2 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)}{r}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of setting $y=mx$ would work.

Note that studying along lines is not sufficient to prove continuity, thus $m$ has to be considered variable, i.e. $m=m(x,y)=\frac yx$.

To avoid confusion, people generally prefer to name this ratio $u$, because $u$ relates more to a variable than $m$ which common usage reserves for constants or integer stuff.

Anyway, you made a calculation mistake

$f(x,mx)=\dfrac{mx^2}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2}}=\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}|x|$

And now since $g(m)=\dfrac{m}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ is bounded then $|f(x,mx)|\le M|x|\to 0$.

[ *$g$ is bounded because $|g(m)|\le\dfrac{|m|}{\sqrt{m^2}}\le 1$* ]

Answer (score 0):

You already saw $2$ nice answers, and here is another one:

$0 \le \dfrac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.